# Entity Framework repository Pattern Inheritance

Tags: c#, linq, design-patterns, ef-code-first, repository-pattern

```
class A 
{
public int id {get; set;}
}

class B : A
{
}

class C : A
{    
}
```

Now does it make sense to have a separate repository for B and C or should I pass in the type information to a method in the Repository for A and return stuff from there.

```
class ARepository : RepositoryBase<Context>,IARepository
{
A GetById (int id )
{
//some linq query here
}

//should this be here or in a separate repository
A GetBByID (int id)
{
}

}
```

The reason I would go for another Repository would be If I wanted

```
class D : A
or Class E : C
```

this could start to get messy and tricky .

So what is the best way of going about this ?

Comment: Do you really want to have separate repository per each entity type?

Comment: @SergRogovtsev not sure that is why the question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer having one large repository per EntityFramework Context, it simplifies maintenance.

Comment: Please elaborate - do you mean using a generic repository pattern (IRepository<T>)?

Comment: No. I mean one repository containing named methods for each entity (e.g. `interface IRepository {A GetA(); B GetB();}`)

Comment: @SergRogovtsev OMG you call this easy to maintain? sounds like a nightmare to me.

Comment: @TsahiAsher Why so? There shouldn't be that much "root" entities per context, so there won't be lots of methods.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev well, the fact that e.g. an Employee has Benefits, doesn't mean I don't want to do CRUD operations directly on a Benefit. It doesn't matter how many root entities you have, you should be able to operate on all of them directly. Of course, your architecture may vary.

Comment: @TsahiAsher *If* you have a lot of root entities in a context, one repository per context would be a mess. But *if* you don't, it'd be easier.